# Homebrew throws error when running make to move binaries

Tags: make, homebrew

I am trying to write a formula for homebrew to install a C++ tool I made. I have the following rule in my makefile to copy `binaryFile` file to `/usr/local/bin`:

```
install:

    @install -m 0755 binaryFile /usr/local/bin
```

When I run `make install`, it correctly copies `binaryFile` to `/usr/local/bin`.

However, when I `brew install` the package, it gives the following error when running the `make install`:

```
install: /usr/local/bin/binaryFile: Operation not permitted
make: *** [install] Error 71
```

I have done some reading and most places say that, when given this error, use `/usr/local/bin/` rather than `/usr/bin` - which is what I am already doing. I don't understand why when homebrew runs make install it behaves differently than when I manually run it.

To see the exact problem I'm having:

```
brew tap k-vernooy/tap
brew install terminalgol
```

Comment: You shouldn't install directly to `/usr/local/bin`. You should install to whatever prefix homebrew sets (which is usually, but no necessarily, somewhere in `/usr/local`).

Comment: I set the install directory to `$(brew --prefix)/bin`, but it still returned the error `Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing things right. A formula is **forbidden** to install binaries, or what ever, into `/usr/local/bin` directly.

As a formula, it should installed all of its content into a path like `/usr/local/Celler/<formula-name>/<version>`, which is called a `prefix` path and represented by `#{prefix}` in ruby. Homebrew will symlink the binary from subfolder `bin/` under this `#{prefix}` into `/usr/local/bin`.

The `#{prefix}` variable from ruby is calculated by Homebrew automatically, following the pattern I mentioned above.

All you should do is to tell the configure file this `prefix` before compile and build.

```ruby
class Wget < Formula
  homepage "https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/"
  url "https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.15.tar.gz"
  sha256 "52126be8cf1bddd7536886e74c053ad7d0ed2aa89b4b630f76785bac21695fcd"

  def install
    system "./configure", "--prefix=#{prefix}"
    system "make", "install"
  end
end
```

Please read the developer documentations and some existing formulae codes before you write your own formulae.

- [Formula Cookbook](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook)
- [Formula API](https://rubydoc.brew.sh/Formula)